# Sorting groups of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

So variations of this have been asked but I can't seem to find what i'm looking for or figure it out myself.  Heres the layout code

```
<div class="original">
<div timestamp="1100">1100</div>
<div timestamp="1000">1000</div>
<div timestamp="100">100</div>
<div timestamp="1530">1530</div>
</div>

<div class="original">
<div timestamp="1500">1500</div>
<div timestamp="700">700</div>
<div timestamp="730">730</div>
<div timestamp="700">700</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is be able to sort the divs inside of each ".original" div and then return them to the div where they started

Heres my current sort code:

```
var myArray = $(".original div");

function compare(a, b) {
    a = parseInt($(a).attr("timestamp"), 10);
    b = parseInt($(b).attr("timestamp"), 10);
    if(a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else if(a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

myArray.sort(compare);
$(".original").append(myArray);
```

So this works if it was just one div with the class original but I want this to work on a bunch of divs with the same class and only return to them the divs that were within them to begin.

Just to be clear my desired result is this:

```
<div class="original">
<div timestamp="100">100</div>
<div timestamp="1000">1000</div>
<div timestamp="1100">1100</div>
<div timestamp="1530">1530</div>
</div>

<div class="original">
<div timestamp="700">700</div>
<div timestamp="700">700</div>
<div timestamp="730">730</div>
<div timestamp="1500">1500</div>
</div>
```

Heres a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5bzZ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
 function compare(a, b) {
           a = parseInt($(a).attr("timestamp"), 10);
           b = parseInt($(b).attr("timestamp"), 10);
           if(a > b) {
               return 1;
           } else if(a < b) {
               return -1;
           } else {
               return 0;
           }
       }
$(".orginal").each(function(){

   var myArray = $("div", $(this));
   myArray.sort(compare);
   $(this).append(myArray);
});
```

hope i help

Answer (score 1):

You can try a for each loop through each `.original` class:

```
/// define compare function

$('.original').each(function () {
    var myArray = $(this).children('div');

    myArray.sort(compare);
    $(this).append(myArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through every Original seperatly:

```
var myOriginals = $("div.original");

myOriginals.each(function(){
    var myArray = $("div", this);
    alert(myArray);
function compare(a, b) {
    a = parseInt($(a).attr("timestamp"), 10);
    b = parseInt($(b).attr("timestamp"), 10);
    if(a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else if(a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

myArray.sort(compare);
$(this).append(myArray);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just golfing!!! [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m5bzZ/4/)

```
function compareX(a, b) { 
  a = $(a).attr("timestamp");
  b = $(b).attr("timestamp"); 
  return ~~a - ~~b;
}
$(".original").each(function(){
  var t = $(this);   
  var myArray = t.children();
  myArray.sort(compareX);
  t.append(myArray);    
});
```